# SSH public key log in suddenly stopped working (CENTOS 6)

Tags: ssh, jenkins, centos, ansible

I was testing a jenkins build job in which I was using ansible to scp a tarball to a number of servers. Below is the ansible yaml file:

```
- hosts: websocket_host
  user: root
  vars:
    tarball: /data/websocket/jenkins/deployment/websocket_host/websocket.tgz
    deploydir: /root
  tasks:
  - name: copy build to websocket server
    action: copy src=$tarball dest=$deploydir/websocket.tgz
  - name: untar build on websocket server
    action: command tar xvfz $deploydir/websocket.tgz -C $deploydir
  - name: restart websocket server
    action: command /root/websocket/bin/websocket restart
```

The first two commands worked successfully with command /root/websocket/bin/websocket restart failing. I have since been able to log in (without a password) to any of the servers defined in my ansible host file for websocket_host. I have verified that all my permissions settings are correct on both the host and client machines. I have tested this from several client machines and they all now require me to enter a password to ssh. Yesterday I was able to ssh (via my public key) no problem. I am using the root user on the host machines and wonder if copying files to the /root directory caused this issue as it was the last command I was able to successfully run via a passwordless ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Jenkins job changed ownership and group of my /root directory. The command: chown root.root /root fixes everything.